# Run VS as Administrator in Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-10, administrator

I have to right click on VS2012 shortcut and "Run As Administrator" every time I want to work. I tried going to the properties and changing the settings, but the settings are disabled:
[image: Properties Window:]

[image: Advanced Properties:]

I saw this:[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654833/how-to-run-visual-studio-as-administrator-by-default) for solution, especially Nate's answer. But I don't get the Compatibility tab. Maybe because I am running Windows 10. I went to the file devenv.exe in Program Files(x86) and even changed the user permission for my account, but it just went back to what it was before right after I closed it.

Anyone know, how to go about it?

Edit After Oz's Answer:
Can you help me with where to find Groups in this?
[image]

Comment: create a new shortcut to **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"** and try to set the option to run as admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This finally worked. I went to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe` as specified by @magicandre1981.

1. Right Click on devenv.exe
2. Chose 'Troubleshoot Compatibility'
3. Check 'Program requires additional permissions.'
4. Then clicked 'Next'
5. Clicked 'Test the program.' Visual Studio started.
6. Clicked 'Next' again.
7. Selected 'Save settings for this program.'
8. Close.