# Orchard Theme Install Fails

Tags: orchardcms, azure-web-app-service, iis-express

When downloading and running Orchard CMS 1.9.2 I am unable to install a Theme because of the following error.

```
"...server does not have write access to the '~/Modules' or '~/Themes' folder of the web site..."
```

This occurs when debugging via Visual Studio 2015 F5 on localhost using IIS Express and also if I deploy the same solution to Azure Web Sites.

How do I configure write access to those folders in both IIS Express and Azure web sites so I can continue testing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For **IIS Express** to have write access to those folder, you need to run Visual Studio as an Administrator. To run Visual Studio as an admin by default, check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654833/how-to-run-visual-studio-as-administrator-by-default).

For **IIS** you need to add grant permissions for the service account that is being used as the IIS application pool identity - as specified in the [Orchard Doc's](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Installing-modules-and-themes-from-the-gallery).

> If your site is running under IIS, make sure you have granted read/write permissions to the ~/Themes folder under the root of your site for the service account that is being used as the IIS application pool identity. However, you should remove the write permissions on a production server.

For **Azure Websites**, simply check out [Whats new for Windows Azure in Orchard 1 7 1](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Whats-new-for-Windows-Azure-in-Orchard-1-7-1)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the IIS Express. I should have figured that one out.  But Configuring Azure to do that is the problem for me. How do you do that?

Comment: I am afraid running VS as Admin has not solved my problem. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a known problem with the current edition of Orchard.

The [Orchard Gallery](http://gallery.orchardproject.net/) is being upgraded and something is wrong with the feed url at the moment.

Update: This is what I was referring to [Module updates not working any more](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6345).