# IISExpress process is blurred out while trying to attach to process in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I've started the app without Debug and then I started the app in debugging mode. I am trying to attach the debugger to the existing process but it's blurred out.

[image]

Comment: Can you try running VS as an administrator?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari That was it, can you post it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run VS with administrator privileges. Right-click Visual Studio, and select `Run as an administrator`.

You can also configure VS so that it always opens with admin privileges. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654833/how-to-run-visual-studio-as-administrator-by-default/9654880#9654880).