# Unable to create website on localhost, Unable to access the IIS metabase

Tags: wcf, service

I was hosting a web service but getting an error "Unable to create a website'http://localhost/IISHostedService. Unable to access the IIS metabase....".
My localhost service is perfectly working, but I did't find the issue.

Please help me and see the below screenshots related to error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error says you do not have sufficient privilege.

When you start visual studio, make sure you start it with [administrative privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654833/how-to-run-visual-studio-as-administrator-by-default).