# How to run DevStudio as an admin from a pinned link?

Tags: associations, admin, administrator

Win10, DevStudio 2017 Community

I have an app that needs to run with highest privileges, but when I start the debugger the first time after launch of DevStudio, it complains I have to run DevStudio with admin privileges. It offers to restart DevStudio with those privileges, which works, but is an unnecessary and time-consuming step.

I've set DevStudio to run as an admin via Properties/Advanced/Run as Administrator. If I launch DevStudio directly, then load the solution, it runs with the correct privileges. However, if I launch DevStudio by association of the .sln, it launches with incorrect privileges.

How do I get DevStudio to run as an admin from the Startup link or any other link to the solution?

My topic is partially covered here and it's how I got DevStudio to run as an admin if I launch it directly: [How to Run Visual Studio as Administrator by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654833/how-to-run-visual-studio-as-administrator-by-default)