# Unable to run the application from VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis

I am running my application using VS 2012 initially, That time it's working fine. After that we installed VS 2015 update 3. Now we are not able to run the application.

Getting **Unable to start the debugging server on the web server. The Underlying connection was closed.An unexpected error occur on a send**.

My application hosted in IIS, host entry fine with host file. I am able to run the application from IIS. And get the Verbosity -Diagnostic output. There is no conflicts between the packages. Firewall port is enabled as well as there is no Anti virus blocking.

Before installing VS 2015 it's working fine, Please let me know what is the issue here. Is there any .netframework conflicts, Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Ensure that you are using VS 2015 with the option **Run as Administrator**. Without it, debugging your apps running on IIS is not possible. See e.g. [How to Run Visual Studio as Administrator by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9654833/1220550).

Comment: Yes Peter, already did the same. Getting the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Try changing the port being used to something other than 80 which may being used by another application.
2. Check to make sure the app pool has the right privileges.
3. Are VS2015 components installed on the remote to allow for VS2015 debugging? See [Installing Remote Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/bt727f1t%28v%3dvs.110%29#installing-the-remote-tools)