# Visual Studio 2022 debugging web application sits forever

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging, .net-framework-version

Developer is debugging a .NET Framework 4.6.2 ASP.NET MVC web application in Visual Studio 2022.  It is running on IIS Express in Google Chrome.  I have downloaded the source code he is using and can successfully run it on my machine without any changes. However, when he runs the application it will open the Chrome window and just sit there with a blank page "loading" indefinitely.  There's no exception being thrown in Visual Studio that I have seen, no log in Event Viewer, and the site itself does not generate any log files or database entries. It just seems stuck.

This developer is a new member of the team and is just getting started with fresh installations of Visual Studio and related tools. I have been using it for years and cannot recall having a similar problem.

**Update**

It appears that IIS Express is running within Visual Studio as "user code" instead of running separately as its own application.  He discovered this by opening the Debug > Windows > Modules window while running the application in debug mode.  It shows tons of IIS express related modules for him which are all counted as "user code".  In my own instance there are 0 modules from IIS Express, let alone any which count as user code.  All my user code modules are actually the code we're trying to debug.  Clearly something different about his setup than mine.  He is on Windows 11 and I am on Windows 10.  He did also say he set up "SQL Server IIS Express Edition" which... I'm not sure if he's confusing SQL Express with IIS somehow.  Or maybe SQL Express comes with its own less-capable version of IIS Express?  I use localdb so it's been quite a long time since I installed SQL Express.

**Update 2**
We are having him completely uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio and IIS Express and any .NET Framework versions on his PC. I kind of wonder if it's not a .NET Framework 4.6.2 compatibility issue in Windows 11.

Comment: Try [running Visual Studio with "Admin" rights](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9654833/1220550).

Comment: @PeterB my instance does not have this option set.  So I don't know if it will make a difference.

Comment: It did not make a difference to run VS 2022 in administrator mode for the sake of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer did not actually work in the long term.  At this time the solution seems to be that he installed Visual Studio 2022 on a different PC which is running Windows 10. I will mark another answer if it can provide an explanation how to run a web application in debug mode in Windows 11.