# How do I properly register the Type Library of A VB.NET COM+ Component?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, com+

I am looking to upgrade legacy VB6 COM+ components to VB.NET components.  I have seemingly upgraded one already, called EventPackage, which has one class, IEventListener.  Another, TradeOrders, `Implements EventPackage.IEventListener`.  When attempting to build TradeOrders, I get the following Errors/Warnings;

1. Cannot load type library for reference "EventPackage". Library not registered. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED))
2. The referenced component 'EventPackage' could not be found.
3. Type 'EventPackage.IEventListener' is not defined.

In the .vbproj, I notice this reference

```
<COMReference Include="EventPackage">
  <Guid>{0D76C094-21A6-4E04-802B-6E539F7102D7}</Guid>
  <Lcid>0</Lcid>
  <VersionMajor>2</VersionMajor>
  <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
  <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
</COMReference>
```

When I search the registry for this Guid, I find nothing.  When using GUIDs for similar COM+ objects, I find them in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{...}\TypeLib` ("..." being the GUID of the other component).  When I go to the registry key name corresponding to EventPackage.IEventListener, I find that there is no `\TypeLib` subkey.  As you might suspect, searching the reg for "0D76C094-21A6-4E04-802B-6E539F7102D7" yields no results.

So I know this must be a registry problem, But I have tried seemingly every google result I have found.  I have tried Regasm and regsvcs .exe's to no avail.  Many pages just tell me that dragging the dll to the COM+ manager should automatically register the component.

So how do I register the Type library?

### Details on how I made EventPackage COM+ component

1. Ran the VB6->VB.NET wizard

Then I added some lines to the assemblyinfo.vb file

1. added `Imports System.EnterpriseServices`
2. added `Imports System.EnterpriseServices`
3. `Imports System.Data.SqlClient`
4. `<Assembly: CLSCompliant(True)>`
5. `<Assembly: AssemblyKeyFileAttribute("...")>` for a strong name
6. `<Assembly: Guid("...")>` (Where "..." is the COM+ CLSID of the old component)

I added the following to the class file IEventListener.VB

1. `Imports System.EnterpriseServices`
2. `<ComClass("...")> _` (Where ... is the proper COM+ CLSID, that is the only argument)
3. `Inherits ServicedComponent`
4. changed the ID made by the Conversion wizard to the proper value (from `<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ProgId("IEventListener_NET.IEventListener)>` to `<System.Runtime.InteropServices.ProgId("EventPackage.IEventListener")> _`

Then I dragged the DLL into the COM+ manager in the proper COM+ application (although, the "Path" is not specified and only says `mscoree.dll`)

Answer (score 0):

I had that dam error (0x8002801D (TYPE_E_LIBNOTREGISTERED)) yesterday, it drove me crazy: [VSTO Add-ins, COMAddIns and RequestComAddInAutomationService](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875278/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationservice)

It might be a red-herring but my answer has similar details about reg keys not existing and etc:

**Right click on Visual Studio (2010) > Run As Administrator > Open Project > Compile!**

Comment: I am using Windows XP, Visual Studio 2008.  Running as administrator.  I have "Register for COMInterop" Checked.

Answer (score 0):

The console command "regsvr32 mydll.dll" will register your COM component.  You should be able then to find the guid under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLASSID then, under which the InprocServer32 folder will have the path to your dll.  This is how COM looks up the dll.

Comment: I am getting the error `EventPAckage.dll was loaded, but the DllRegisterServer entry point was not found.  THis file can not e registered`.  I am looking thru other StackOverflow questions to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem here is that you haven't generated a type library for your .NET component. I know you said you used regasm - but did you use the right command line?

- **Start Menu** => **Programs** => **Microsoft .NET Framework SDK vX.Y** => **SDK Command Prompt**.
- In this command line line, type: **regasm /tlb:Mydll.dll**

Comment: So, when I first I got an error saying "Error RA0000 : No input file has been specified.  Then I tried `regasm EventPackage.dll /tlb:EventPackage.dll`.  This gave me the error `error RA0000 : An error occurred while saving the exported type library: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`.  I have tried deleting the old tlb, stopping iis, closing all dev/ie/iis tools but the error persists