# How to register WinSCP .NET assembly in VB6

Tags: vb6, sftp, winscp, winscp-net

I want to convert FTP to SFTP in an old VB6 application. So I was suggested to use WinSCP.

WinSCP has WinSCPnet.dll which needs to be registered in VB6 but I am unable to add it as a reference in VB6. I tried *Projects -> Reference -> Browse -> Add.* But I'm getting

> Can't add a reference for the specified file.

So how will I register this DLL in VB6 and use it?

Comment: And what did the *Projects -> Reference -> browse -> add* do?

Comment: See here: [How do I properly register the Type Library of A VB.NET COM+ Component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903671/how-do-i-properly-register-the-type-library-of-a-vb-net-com-component)

Comment: As you can find on the site of winscp, and in my post.

Comment: "unable to add it as a reference" - Why? What does it do? Did you [register the assembly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#registering)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On their website I found this:

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\<version>\RegAsm.exe WinSCPnet.dll /codebase /tlb
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe WinSCPnet.dll/codebase /tlb:WinSCPnet32.tlb
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe WinSCPnet.dll /codebase /tlb:WinSCPnet64.tlb
```

read this part of the site:

https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_install#registering

Answer (score 0):

I am able to register WinSCP successfully. 
Thanks for all the help.
As nabuchodonossor suggested in the post we need to first register for COM.
this is the command:
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe WinSCPnet.dll /codebase /tlb:WinSCPnet32.tlb
Once this was done I went to Project -> References -> Browse -> Choose WinSCPnet32.tlb from system32 folder.

This will get the task done.

Answer (score 0):

You should **register through command line as an administrator**.

I have been trying to register my `.dll` library for a while after switching to Windows 10 and everything was failing until I did that.