# Casting issue when attempting to call code in a VSTO add-in from another process

Tags: vsto, office-addins

I am attempting to call code in a VSTO add-in.

The first place I landed in my searches was [MS Walkthrough Calling Code in an Application Level Add-in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608621.aspx)

1. I made a new VSTO project for Outlook.
2. In this project I created the following **Note Attributes same as in Walkthrough** and added the RequestComAddInAutomationService

   [image]
3. I then created a WPF application project and added my VSTO addin as a reference.
4. The following is what happens.  Please note that if I simply use the addin Object I can call my code, but I am unable to cast the interface.
   [image]

The first thing I have noticed is that [This blog uses different attributes.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/08/11/why-your-comaddin-object-should-derive-from-standardolemarshalobject.aspx)

For anyone landing here and looking for a similar question in C# there are lots, [this one being very similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875278/vsto-add-ins-comaddins-and-requestcomaddinautomationservice) however seems very user / computer specific.

So could anyone please help me to understand why I cannot cast the interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the Interface was not registering properly for COM.  Once the registration is done properly then the cast worked.