# Cannot create C++ projects in VS 2013 community

Tags: c++, visual-studio

After I chose "Win32 Console Application" or "Win32 Project" and went through the wizard, I got an empty solution. And the "New Project" dialog poped up again:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/87VOf.png]

When I tried the project types under the CLR category, I got an error:

[image: error]

It says something about accessing the OLE system registry.

But Windows Store C++ Application projects and other languages work just fine.

I've tried to:

- Use the repair function provided by the installer.
- Run `vs_community.exe /uninstall /force` and reinstall it.
- Delete the `ProjectTemplatesCache` and `ItemTemplatesCache` directory in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE` and run `devenv` to install them again.
- Run as Administrator and turn off security softwares.

Comment: Do you have any security-tools / scanners installed/running?

Comment: Seems there is problem accessing registry. Make sure that you are logged into the computer as local Administrator, or are part of the local Administrator group.

Comment: Try this?http://stackoverflow.com/a/10889575/1587755

Answer (score 0):

I would have put this in comments but apparently you need more reputation points to comment than you do for an answer.

I recently had an OLE system registry error, mine occurred in a different way but it was tied to windows updates. It fixed itself when I uninstalled VS, installed updates, restarted computer, and re-installed VS(if you are installing from an exe and not a disc make sure you re-download the exe).
That solve the problem for me.